# Unable to extract json response

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I am trying to extract a JSON response.When I try to access the object within the json array it returns undefined

```
  weather=  [{"id":711,"main":"Smoke","description":"smoke","icon":"50d"}]
 var x=JSON.stringify(weather)
 x[0].main= returns =>undefined
```

Comment: You've stringified an array with an object; what's supposed to be the problem? There's no problem statement here that matches the code.

Comment: Whats your expected output here ? I do not see an issue with your code at current!

Comment: i just want to retrieve the data fields within weather, but it always returns undefined

Comment: It's a string. You had an object, you turned it into a string. `weather[0].main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) OR [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) function to get all you JSON data. You do **not** need to use `JSON.stringify` in your response.

**Demo:**

```js
let weather = [{
  "id": 711,
  "main": "Smoke",
  "description": "smoke",
  "icon": "50d"
}]

weather.map(function(x) {
  console.log(x.id) //711
  console.log(x.main) //Smoke
  console.log(x.description) //smoke
  console.log(x.icon) //50d
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish or what you've tried, but here is how that works:

```js
const weather = [{"id":711,"main":"Smoke","description":"smoke","icon":"50d"}]
document.querySelector('#id').textContent = weather[0].id
document.querySelector('#json').textContent = JSON.stringify(weather)
```

```html
ID:
<div id="id"></div>
Stringified JSON:
<div id="json"></div>
```

To access an element of an array you can reference an index or loop through it:

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3];
myArray[0] // 1
myArray[1] // 2
myArray[2] // 3

for (let i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

To access a property of an object you can either use dot notation or the key name as the index:

```
const myObject = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
myObject.a // 1
myObject['b'] // 2
```

`JSON.stringify` converts your JSON into a string.  This is useful for sending it over a connection to a host that may or may not recognize JSON.